# The space of smooth functions is a vector bundle

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles

I am reading these [lecture notes](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Ewestra/calabiyau3.pdf) on Calabi-Yau manifolds and, at the beginning of page 4, the author says that space $C^\infty(M)$ of smooth functions on a smooth manifold $M$ is a vector bundle. I really do not understand why this is true. I do not even know how to define a projection map $C^\infty(M)\longrightarrow M$. Can you help me?

Comment: looking at those notes, it seems the author means that $C^\infty(M)$ is the space of sections of a vector bundle (namely of $\mathbb R\times M\to M$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is being imprecise. They're alluding to the [Serre-Swan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem), which gives for a smooth connected manifold $M$ an equivalence of categories between smooth vector bundles on $M$ and finitely generated projective $C^{\infty}(M)$-modules with the equivalence given by taking the space of smooth sections. $C^{\infty}(M)$ itself is the space of smooth sections of the trivial line bundle $\mathbb{R}$; that's the bundle the author means.

Comment: If you take a look at Exercise 1.4 on the same page the author also asks to give a description of the "bundle" in terms of Def 1.1. They are very imprecise, I guess!